# Alfresco: NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/channels/SeekableByteChannel

Tags: java, alfresco

Installed and ran Alfresco 4.2 with Java 6 on Linux, I get this error:

> NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/channels/SeekableByteChannel

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is due to using Java 6 (or earlier), whereas Java 7 is required.

1. Install Java JDK 7 (or later)
2. Add this line at the top of /bin/catalina.sh :

   JAVA_HOME="/path/to/jdk7"